# I am employed full-time with a part-time PhD. Can I take up an internship and get paid in my home country to bypass limits on number of hours worked?

Tags: phd, united-kingdom, germany, legal-issues, working-time

I am working as an International research assistant in a public organization in Germany. I am also doing a part-time PhD from a different university, and the topic of the PhD is different. So, I am working full-time 40 hours and doing a part-time PhD 4 hours per week (not being paid). I have informed my employer that I am working for my PhD and spending 4 hours per week, and they gave official permission for doing so.

Now, I got a summer internship offer from a company based in London, and he will pay some grants for two months full-time.

Legally, I am not now allowed to work for an internship, but this opportunity is from a very big company. It will also help me in my PhD. In the end, I want to continue in the direction of my PhD topic.

Suppose I finish the internship and ask the employer to pay the stipend in the bank account of my home country. Is it possible to bypass the process of maximum working hours?
I do not want to hide my income, but I am sure my employer will not allow me to join the internship.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What about getting an unpaid leave for the time of the internship?

Comment: I notice you keep asking the same type of questions over again - you asked in essence the same on workplace a while ago: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166409/working-hours-in-eu-with-multiple-jobs, and also previously here (several times, in fact!). What's the point of that? Do you want someone to promise you you can game the system without being caught?

Comment: Yes, please avoid posting duplicate questions; this is not allowed. There may be some subtle differences between the posts (and the UK's legal situation may be evolved), so I will not hammer anything this time. But more broadly, please do note that we are academics, not forensic accountants or lawyers, so (1) most of us have no expertise to offer you about your legal options, and (2) we are, of course, not going to advise you with resect to illegal options.

Comment: @cag51 People who want to go for illegal options don't post publicly, the question was posted to get the opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Like always in life, it is your decision whether you want to do something illegal, and to judge whether the risk of getting caught (and the resulting potential long-term damage) is worth it. I don't think we can give advice on this, nor do I think we should. Note that such an action comes with follow-up questions, like whether you would like to equally hide this from the tax authorities. Also, it is not clear whether/how you will manage to hide this fact from your employer, and keep in mind that you might not have all factors under your control (imagine you appear on their web site!).

However, there might be another option, which is what I would recommend: You can ask your employer in Germany for an unpaid leave for the duration of your internship. Depending on the nature of your employment in Germany (I assume it is in the public sector), it is likely that you are even entitled to such an unpaid leave.

EDIT: Just to clarify: In the public sector in Germany, you have the right to do a side job up to ~8h/week. Your employer can't forbid you that, unless it conflicts with your main job (or with working in the public sector in general). You are, however, obliged to inform your employer and, depending on the nature of that side job, get permission ("anzeigepflichtig"/"genehmigungspflichtig"). Thus, if you stop working on your PhD during the duration of the internship, you would have 8h/week to work on the internship, without getting into any trouble. (Unless the pay is disproportionately high, that is.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It make senses

Comment: @Yes, pay is high. but is it make difference between high pay and stipend?

Comment: @AlexKujur The pay can be an issue if it is out of scale relative to your regular pay (but doesn't have to be an issue). I believe that if it is >40% of your regular (40h/week) pay for the 8h/week side job, this is considered problematic (but not per se illegal).

Comment: okay, thanks @user151413 for making suggestion